# If we fit two Bayesian models to the same data with the same parameter, if there a way to compare model fit based on posterior interval widths?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

Suppose that we have a dataset with a parameter of interest. If I were to fit two Bayesian models on the same data, and then generate the MCMC draws, I can come up with the posterior interval on the parameter of interest (the credible interval). Suppose one model results in a interval that is wider than another. Does this suggest anything about model fit? What can we glean from this?

Comment: Consider the ultimate case when one of the priors is a Dirac mass, as the resulting interval is of length zero.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is the takeaway that a comparison really exists if the likelihood is the same? In general does this mean a comparison doesn't really exist?

Comment: No this is not what I meant: comparison is feasible via the Bayes factor, not credible intervals...